# Study the convergence and calculate the improper integral

Tags: integration, analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Hoping someone can help me with this one.

Study the convergence and, in case it's affirmative, calculate the improper integral:

$\int_a^b{\frac{x dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}}} $ , where $ b>a $

Comment: I might begin by looking at specific cases, e.g. $a=0,b=1$, in the absence of a clever idea (such as a change of variable).

Comment: @amWhy I'm simply trying to pass my exam here and trying to learn something from you guys. If you don't want to answer my questions, please be on your way. After all, it's a public forum meant for learning and sharing knowledge. If I could help somebody here, I would do it wholeheartedly. I repeat, if YOU don't want to help me, maybe someone else might, and I would be very grateful to that said person. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

substitute $$\sqrt{x^2-x(a+b)+ab}=t+x$$

Comment: it is the so-called Euler substitution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution

Answer (score 2):

$I=\displaystyle\int _{a}^{b} \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}} dx$

use property $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} f(a+b-x)dx=\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ and add both I's together then you will get;

$I=\dfrac{a+b}{2}\displaystyle\int _{a}^{b} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}} dx$

substitute $(x-a)=t(b-x)\implies x=\dfrac{a+tb}{t+1}\implies dx=\dfrac{b-a}{(t+1)^2}dt$

$$I=\dfrac{a+b}{2}\displaystyle\int _{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{t^\frac{-1}{2}}{t+1} dt$$

$$I=\dfrac{a+b}{2}\displaystyle\int _{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{t^\frac{-1}{2}}{t+1} dt$$

substitute $t=x^2\implies 2xdx=dt$

$$I={(a+b)}.\displaystyle\int _{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{x^2+1} dx$$

$$I=\dfrac{\pi(a+b)}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try using this now. Much appreciated!

Comment: @ Edward B: glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Hints.

The indefinite integral exists and it's pretty trivial to evaluate:

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}} = -\frac{\sqrt{x-a} \sqrt{b-x} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a+b-2 x}{2 \sqrt{x-a} \sqrt{b-x}}\right)}{\sqrt{(x-a) (b-x)}}$$

Where as **your** definite integral is simply $\pi$.

You have a square root of a second degree equation in the denominator. Start from it.

You can also come to the final result by taking limits.

Comment: hi Mr Neumann, i think soo trivial is it not to compute, think about the parameters